# Adding Image To freeCodeCamp Project

Tags: html, css, image, frontend, project

I fairly started coding. I have a project on freeCodeCamp where I am required to add an image to my website. Normally I would add the image to project file and use its path as a link for the image. There is no room for this on my project. How do I add the image?

I have tried using image links from other websites on the internet. I have also tried to download the image, save it on my google and use a shareable link (anyone with the link can access). I tried to upload the image to imgur.com but apparently Imgur is not allowed in my region.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to find the URL of an image that can be accessed on the internet and add it to your image element like this:

```
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1575936123452-b67c3203c357?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80" />
```

I tried this on the Tribute Page challenge for freeCodeCamp, and it works.

Comment: How do I find such image?

Comment: @HildaEnyioko You can go into a web browser like Chrome and search for an image. Click Tools -> Usage rights -> Creative Common license. Right click on an image and select Copy link address. Then paste that into your src attribute.